# key-shortcut accessible command-history (in gnome-terminal) for irssi sessions needed!

Tags: history, irc, irssi, bash-history

I use gnome-terminal in combination with [irssi](http://www.irssi.org/) and I am wondering if there's anything like `.bash_history` logfile for irssi, that can be used/implemented/set up, that enables one to retrieve previously typed commands, like `/server xxx`, `/j #channel` etc.. also in a later anew started session, by using gnome-terminals standard key-shortcuts like <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>.

It is really troublesome to repeatedly type all the commands again and again while not being connected to any `/server` the next day, so any help here is much appreciated. --Thank you!!

---

Edit: When I am prompted to connect to any /server of my choice, I would like to use the key-shortcut prior mention, that then brings up my previous choices of connected servers/commands, like `/server irc.blah01.com`, `/server irc.blah02.com`, `/server irc.blah03.com` etc.. I simply can then skip through and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of typing the exact command and server address again and again. (I know about the auto-connect function, but I prefer the other option, if it is one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [history_search.pl](http://scripts.irssi.org/scripts/history_search.pl) script from [irssi.org](http://scripts.irssi.org/) in combination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> worked quite nicely in the end!

**How to use it**:

1. First do: `/bind ^R /history_search`.
2. Then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type what you're searching for.
3. Optionally, you can bind something to `/history_search -forward` to go forward in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly - I'm not certain what you are asking. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and type the start of the command, and it should appear there. You can then use the arrow keys to edit it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tim. It doesn't work with the provided command. I'll have to invest more time to find the answer. Just though someone can provide a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to read up on this
http://www.irssi.org/documentation

From memory, there is a "$HOME/.irssi/" directory which you will find config files in, and may create new... on your own.

I had it set up to do `/server ...` wait a bit, set nick, then join a specific channel - as it was started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hannu and I edited my question. I'll do some reading then.